# How many times has the Doctor worn this orange spacesuit?

Tags: doctor-who, clothing

In the TV series *Doctor Who*, there's a particular orange spacesuit that the Doctor pops up wearing time and time again, often in 'base under siege' episodes. This isn't restricted to one regeneration of the Doctor or one showrunner; see the following pictures from *The Satan Pit* (Series 2), *The Waters of Mars* (2008-10 specials), and *Kill the Moon* (Series 8) respectively:

[image: The Satan Pit]
[image: The Waters of Mars]
[image: Kill the Moon]

**In how many episodes has he used this same spacesuit?**

Could they be the same one in-universe (perhaps the spacesuit he keeps somewhere in the TARDIS for whenever he has to go out onto a planet with no atmosphere), or must they be different items (but perhaps produced in the same factory)?

Comment: david tennet matt smith and peter capaldi have worn the same spacesuit

Comment: @AndrewCasali They have? When did Matt Smith wear it?

Comment: matt smth wore it in the series 7 episode hide with clara

Answer (score 11):

### Five (possible six)

Or four/five, if you want to count two-parters as one episode.

1. "The Impossible Planet"

   [image: David Tennant in orange suit as people rush by]
2. "The Satan Pit"

   [image: David Tennant in orange suit looking at Satan]
3. "The Waters of Mars"

   [image: David Tennant in orange suit being the Time Lord Victorious]
4. "Hide"

   [image: Matt Smith in orange suit in the TARDIS]

   The suit does appear slightly different here; the black harness and the Starbase 6 insignia are both gone. However, just from comparing images we can see that they're too similar for coincidence; the center strap and the helmet bracket in particular. He also wears the helmet in this episode, and it's the same one Tennant wore:

   [image: Matt Smith in orange suit and helmet]

   [image: David Tennant in orange suit and helmet]

   Whether the two suits are, in fact, the same, or whether the Doctor replaced it with a different one of the same model, is impossible to determine.
5. "Kill the Moon"

   [image: Peter Capaldi, Clara, and Courtney in orange suits]

   Here we can see that the Doctor has two more identical suits.

### "42"

The Tenth Doctor wears a bright orange spacesuit on one other occasion: the episode "42"; it's hard to tell if the suits are the same:

[image: David Tennant in orange suit in shadows]

They do appear substantially similar, but the helmet is different and we can't see the Starbase 6 insignia. YMMV.

### Honourable mention

Orson Pink, from "Listen":

[image: Orson Pink in orange suit]

Comment: how did orson pink get the spacesuit the doctor is the only one that had it

Comment: @AndrewCasali There were other people on Starbase 6 besides the Doctor; perhaps Orson had been stationed there sometime in his past, and kept the suit. It's all speculation, though, and never explained in the show

Comment: how did he have spare spacesuits for Clara and Courtney

Comment: @AndrewCasali How does anyone get spacesuits? Presumably he bought or otherwise acquired them

Comment: why did he were the same spacesuit for 3 regeneration david tennet matt smith and peter capaldi

Comment: @AndrewCasali Probably he had it all the way through.

Comment: im suprised he still kepet it

Comment: @AndrewCasali He has an infinite amount of space in the TARDIS, why wouldn't he keep it? He has a large variety of clothing - as seen in [The Christmas Invasion](https://youtu.be/vu1C1Wmj3Xc) - some of it worn by previous regenerations, some we've not seen him wear on screen.

Comment: @Adeptus Not to mention [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rH2QIAkyfCQ).

Comment: I'd like to accept this, but ... what about the suit Clara was wearing in S9E5, *The Girl Who Died*? Was that the same one too?

Comment: Unless he keeps it in his pocket the one he wore in "42" would be a different one in-universe as he didn't have access to the TARDIS at the time.

Comment: @JasonBaker - I presume it's the same spacesuit at different point in its own timeline.

Comment: The good news is that at 5'11.5" (1.82m) (Smith), 6' (1.83m) (Capaldi) and 6'1" (1.85m) (Tennant), the suit didn't need much tailoring between Doctors.